# gmail social auth using wso2 idenity manager

Tags: authentication, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0 Where my API's are managed in API manager and users are in WSO2 Identity server database. Now we are migrating to gmail based social auth. we are getting rid of the database and every user will be using gmail social auth.
How to achieve this using WSO2 Identity manager? Can scopes work along with this?

How can I handle the login/redirect pages in these scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Google as a federated authenticator to the WSO2 IS. After that whenever you login, Google will be used as the authenticator instead of internal IS user store.

If you are talking about Google level scopes, yes you can manage that. It is shown in the documentation[1] or if you are talking about the API manager level scopes, nothing will affect that.

When you are authenticating, IS will automatically redirect you to the Google login page.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+Google

Comment: Thanks.Let me have a look at the doc.